# pyttsx3 not working on python 3.7 no module found

Tags: module, text-to-speech, pywin32, sys

I am receiving the following error with the following code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.runAndWait
engine.say("Hello")
```

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py",
 line 20, in init
         eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
       File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\weakref.py",
 line 137, in \_\_getitem\_\_
         o = self.data[key]()
     KeyError: None
```

During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\Desktop\app1\APP.py", line 3, in <module>
         engine = pyttsx3.init()
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py",
 line 22, in init
         eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py",
 line 30, in __init__
         self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py",
 line 50, in __init__
         self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
       File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py",
 line 127, in import_module
         return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py",
 line 3, in <module>
         import win32com.client
       File "C:\Users\ProBook\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py",
 line 5, in <module>
         import win32api, sys, os
     ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? I already tried installing and re-installing the packages as well as python several times

Comment: Did you `pip install pywin32`?

Comment: Yes i installed all of the packages needed I even tried with pypiwin32

Comment: It's ***pywin32***. Try opening an interpreter console and type `import sys`, `import os`, `import win32api` on 3 separate lines, and check which gets the error. Secondly, did you install the modules on the right *Python* installation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default sapi5 engine is missing.
Try to explicitly specify the language engine.

```
pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
```

If the problem persists, try installing espeak and initializing the pyttsx with it.
More info [there](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx3.init)

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` i had the same problem ..this will upgrade your pip packages ..it worked for me though

Answer (score 0):

if pyttsx3 module not installed in your operating system just write these command on Anaconda Prompt or Python command

```
pip install pyttsx3==2.71 OR pip install -U pyttsx3==2.71
```